# What does the value 'WakeupTotalCnt' (healthstatus) mean?

Tags: tapkey

What is this value? The times a lock woke up, or if it really opened? Or maybe something else?

Here is some text, otherwise I could not pass the quality standards of s.o. Sorry for that.

Stan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your are talking about the health status of Tapkey Locks documented here:
https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_access_management_web_api_v1/#/Bound%20Locks/BoundLocks_GetById

The `WakeupTotakCnt` is not related to unlock events. It's an internal measurement which is not relevant for third parties. That is the reason why it is not noted in the documentation. It is a counter, how often the lock woke up from energy saving mode to handle all kinds of events.